# string appending wipes the string?

Tags: c++, csv, parsing, googletest, readline

I have written the following test in GoogleTest. All this is doing is reading a csv file and printing the lines to console, replacing commas with semicolons.

```
TEST(FlaAlgoGyroAnomalyBehavioral, imu_2_gz_stiction){
    std::ifstream input_file("../imu_2_gz_anom_test.csv");

    std::string line;

    int ctr = 0;
    std::stringstream output;
    while(std::getline(input_file, line)){
        ctr++;
        if (ctr <= 3){
            continue;
        }
        if (ctr >= 10){
            break;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> vect;
        std::istringstream ss(line);

        std::string token;

        while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')){
            token.append(";");
            output << token;
        }
        output << std::endl;


    }
    output.flush();
    FAIL() << output.str();

}
```

For some reason, this just prints the following:

```
;
;
;
;
;
;
```

But, when I remove the `token.append(";");` line, I get the output I want (without the semicolons of course):

```
2970119168634936-0.012451171875-0.0080566406251.011474609375-0.3967285156250.5645751953125-1.0986328125-0.01220703125-0.0114746093750.9990234375-1.2359619140625-0.8087158203125-0.1068115234375-0.00927734375-0.0129394531251.0068359375-1.037597656250.30517578125-0.671386718750.008056640625-0.01171875-0.99462890625-0.518798828125-0.213623046875-0.183105468750.006591796875-0.009033203125-0.984619140625-0.2136230468750.6103515625-0.59509277343750.009765625-0.0078125-0.98339843750.0457763671875-0.74768066406250.045776367187536.3880126182965335.5914826498422736.9400630914826535.3627760252365934.3927444794952735.28391167192429-2.6528878649401122e-081.654520929150749e-070.0002421037497697398-0.0086239615484373640.0038406856219808105-0.00744516910344827925.2812289589963121
2970219168714936-0.01220703125-0.0080566406251.01220703125-0.427246093750.5645751953125-1.0986328125-0.01171875-0.011718750.99853515625-1.40380859375-1.11389160156250.0-0.009033203125-0.013183593751.00732421875-0.99182128906250.2288818359375-0.915527343750.0078125-0.01171875-0.99462890625-0.4119873046875-0.213623046875-0.183105468750.006591796875-0.009033203125-0.9841308593750.16784667968750.335693359375-0.6408691406250.009765625-0.007568359375-0.9836425781250.2593994140625-0.7781982421875-0.259399414062536.380126182965335.5914826498422736.9321766561514235.3548895899053634.4085173501577335.27602523659306-3.641800461195998e-081.1611859207505403e-070.0002421232493361458-0.0121207276606583040.008199632247851696-0.00632870342087699125.281208200785641
2970319168794936-0.01220703125-0.00781251.011474609375-0.41198730468750.5645751953125-1.0833740234375-0.012451171875-0.011718750.9990234375-1.40380859375-0.8392333984375-0.091552734375-0.009033203125-0.0129394531251.0068359375-0.36621093750.335693359375-0.7629394531250.00830078125-0.011474609375-0.994384765625-0.3814697265625-0.1983642578125-0.19836425781250.00634765625-0.0087890625-0.984619140625-0.2746582031250.6256103515625-0.549316406250.009521484375-0.0078125-0.98339843751.312255859375-0.8087158203125-0.4882812536.3958990536277635.6072555205047436.9479495268138835.3706624605678234.4085173501577335.29968454258675-7.500008614158558e-091.4504682610549935e-070.00024209351977333426-0.0088361466623609890.008187172170437407-0.00522122172696981625.2813222506068881
2970419168874936-0.011962890625-0.00781251.01171875-0.427246093750.5645751953125-1.1444091796875-0.011962890625-0.011718750.9990234375-1.2054443359375-1.03759765625-0.0152587890625-0.00927734375-0.0129394531251.0068359375-0.427246093750.3662109375-0.50354003906250.0078125-0.011962890625-0.9951171875-0.3814697265625-0.1983642578125-0.1525878906250.0068359375-0.0087890625-0.984863281250.2441406250.3814697265625-0.65612792968750.009765625-0.008056640625-0.9841308593751.068115234375-0.6866455078125-0.106811523437536.4116719242902235.599369085173536.9479495268138835.3943217665615234.3927444794952735.25236593059937-3.643257784347043e-081.3461932724112557e-070.0002421726530883461-0.0102891171991359440.00894796357897576-0.00544272234037634925.2812807642699051
2970519168954936-0.012451171875-0.0080566406251.01220703125-0.41198730468750.579833984375-1.1444091796875-0.01171875-0.0114746093750.999267578125-1.64794921875-0.946044921875-0.0457763671875-0.009033203125-0.0129394531251.007568359375-1.05285644531250.2899169921875-0.68664550781250.008056640625-0.01171875-0.994873046875-0.3204345703125-0.1678466796875-0.183105468750.007080078125-0.008544921875-0.98486328125-0.28991699218750.5645751953125-0.53405761718750.009521484375-0.0078125-0.9843750.06103515625-0.7019042968750.09155273437536.3880126182965335.63091482649842636.9637223974763435.3785488958990534.38485804416403435.26813880126183-5.308616213284267e-091.4426949235257783e-070.00024223169020842764-0.0090837602328974750.0067885839598602615-0.00798822657088749125.2813015224805751
2970619169034936-0.01171875-0.00781251.011962890625-0.44250488281250.6103515625-1.1444091796875-0.011962890625-0.011718750.998779296875-1.1138916015625-0.946044921875-0.1068115234375-0.0087890625-0.0129394531251.0068359375-1.037597656250.1983642578125-0.915527343750.008056640625-0.01171875-0.99462890625-0.30517578125-0.152587890625-0.1525878906250.006591796875-0.0087890625-0.9846191406250.2746582031250.42724609375-0.7019042968750.009765625-0.0078125-0.9836425781250.2288818359375-0.8087158203125-0.21362304687536.3958990536277635.62302839116719636.9479495268138835.3706624605678234.400630914826535.26813880126183-1.773620361689154e-081.0525636184866016e-070.00024212291464209557-0.0105748458736343310.007961260052979924-0.00717816010364913325.2812911734596041
```

I don't understand what is going on here!

Comment: You should remove the Google test part of this and just write a simple C++ function that all can compile and run.

Comment: Remove code until the problem goes away. Then add back the most recently removed code. Continue until you can't remove anything more. And show sample input; the code **probably** doesn't need to read nine lines and ignore three of them. Try it with a single string that duplicates one of your input lines. Keep making the example smaller until you can't go any further. Then, if you still haven't seen what the problem is, make sure that the remaining code compiles, runs, and shows the problem. Then post it here.

Comment: I recommend using a debugger.  Place a breakpoint at the `append` statement.  Watch the `token` variable first, then step once and see how the `token` variable changed.

Comment: *replacing commas with semicolons.* -- Why not a simple call to [std::replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)?

Comment: Adding in all the missing pieces from the code, it does not repro on my machine.  Could be the issue is in the code not shown.  Could be control characters in the line or token string from the CSV file.  A [mcve] would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the CSV file you are reading has windows line endings, `\r\n`. The `getline` call which reads the line will read up to the `\r` and discard the newline character, with the result that the last field in each line will end with a solitary carriage return. The semicolon you then append will be placed after the carriage return, causing it to be printed at the left margin.

Apparently, when you then send a newline character with `std::eol`, your terminal emulator clears the rest of the output line, something which it doesn't do when the carriage return is immediately followed by a newline character. That seems like odd behaviour, but I'm sure whoever implemented it had good intentions.

Try removing the windows line endings with `dos2unix` or check to see if the last character of `line` is a carriage return (and erase it, if it is) before creating the `istringstream`.